# How to get the first characters in a string? (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, string, substring

I want to get a substring out of a string which starts with either `"<ONLINE>"` or `"<OFFLINE>"` (which should become my substring). When I try to create a Range object, I can easily access the the first character by using `startIndex` but how do I get the index of the closing bracket of my substring which will be either the 8th or 9th character of the full string?

**UPDATE:**

A simple example:

```
let onlineString:String = "<ONLINE> Message with online tag!"

let substring:String = // Get the "<ONLINE> " part from my string?

let onlineStringWithoutTag:String = onlineString.replaceOccurances(of: substring, with: "")

// What I should get as the result: "Message with online tag!"
```

So basically, the question is: what do I do for `substring`?

Comment: can you show some code of how you're creating your range object?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Just updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did not want to use range

```
let onlineString:String = "<ONLINE> Message with online tag!"

let substring:String = onlineString.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]

print(substring) // <ONLINE>
```

Comment: that means ">" could never be included in the string outside of the tag.

Comment: You want index 0, not index 1.  You could use `onlineString.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]` instead to preserve the ">".

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks, that worked! But can you explain why didn't have to specify that the part you wanted to get rid of started with `"<"`. You only specified the end of the substring that was taken out. And also, what is the `[1]` referring to?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Never mind, I just got it. Basically, you're just splitting up the entire into pieces (which are put in an array of String objects) at every point the inserted character occurs, right? And the `[1]` refers to the second String object in that array.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann whoops for some reason I thought he wanted the trailing text.  Edited to match comment

Comment: @MrFlynn Actually, I WAS looking for the trailing text, haha! But that's okay, I know how to get that now: I'll just implement a custom separator in the string, which I know will only occur once, something like: `"::"` for example. Wouldn't be smart to use `" "` as the separator in your example, since every word in the string would become a separate String object and I have no idea how many words are going to be in it. Just to be clear: the `"<ONLINE/OFFLINE>::"` part gets controlled by me and whatever comes after that is dependent on user interactions, so I have no control over that.

Comment: Haha whoops again, glad you figured it out.  If you are just using the <Online> as a way to tag, you can also just test if the string contains online.  IE if onlineString.contains("<ONLINE>") { //online }

Answer (score 10):

```
let name = "Ajay"

// Use following line to extract first chracter(In String format)

print(name.characters.first?.description ?? "");

// Output : "A"
```

Comment: This was great. Thanks

Comment: In swift 4.2 it says 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly.

Comment: This is wrong. As per Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description) it is strongly discouraged to call this property directly:  *Calling this property directly is discouraged. Instead, convert an instance of any type to a string by using the String(describing:) initializer. This initializer works with any type, and uses the custom description property for types that conform to CustomStringConvertible*

Answer (score 4):

The correct way would be to use indexes as following:

```
let string = "123 456"
let firstCharIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let firstChar = string.substring(to: firstCharIndex)
print(firstChar)
```

Answer (score 2):

This Code provides you the first character of the string.
Swift provides this method which returns character? you have to wrap it before use

> ```
> let str = "FirstCharacter"
> print(str.first!)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to OOPer's:

```
let string = "<ONLINE>"

let closingTag = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ">")
if let closingTagIndex = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: closingTag) {
    let mySubstring = string.substring(with: string.startIndex..<closingTagIndex.upperBound)
}
```

Or with regex:

```
let string = "<ONLINE>jhkjhkh>"

if let range = string.range(of: "<[A-Z]+>", options: .regularExpression) {
    let mySubstring = string.substring(with: range)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5

```
let someString = "Stackoverflow"
let firstChar = someString.first?.description ?? ""
print(firstChar)
```

Comment: This is wrong. As per Apple's doc it is strongly discouraged to call this property directly: *Calling this property directly is discouraged. Instead, convert an instance of any type to a string by using the String(describing:) initializer. This initializer works with any type, and uses the custom description property for types that conform to CustomStringConvertible*

Answer (score 0):

This code be some help for your purpose:

```
let myString = "<ONLINE>abc"
if let rangeOfClosingAngleBracket = myString.range(of: ">") {
    let substring = myString.substring(to: rangeOfClosingAngleBracket.upperBound)
    print(substring) //-><ONLINE>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let firstCharIndex = oneGivenName.index(oneGivenName.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let firstChar = String(oneGivenName[..<firstCharIndex])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let character = MyString.first
```

it's an simple way to get first character from string in swift.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5** extension

```
extension String {
    var firstCharactor: String? {
        guard self.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(self.prefix(1))
    }
}
```